# Can't properly serialize forms into a json

Tags: html, json, go, serialization

I'm trying to make a web application in golang that allows you enter in details of a receipt into different forms, then those form inputs get serialized into a json object. However I'm having trouble serializing the forms because whenever I try to "submit" my receipt, I get an error.

This is the main.go

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "html/template"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "strconv"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

type Item struct {
    ShortDescription string `json:"shortDescription"`
    Price            string `json:"price"`
}

type Receipt struct {
    Retailer     string `json:"retailer"`
    PurchaseDate string `json:"purchaseDate"`
    PurchaseTime string `json:"purchaseTime"`
    Items        []Item `json:"items"`
    Total        string `json:"total"`
    ReceiptID    int    `json:"receiptID"`
}

var receiptIDCounter int

var receipts = make(map[int]Receipt)

func main() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()

    r.HandleFunc("/", homeHandler).Methods("GET")
    r.HandleFunc("/submit", submitHandler).Methods("POST")
    r.HandleFunc("/receipt/{id}", receiptHandler).Methods("GET")

    http.Handle("/", r)

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}

func homeHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    t, err := template.ParseFiles("templates/home.html")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        http.Error(w, "Internal server error", http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    err = t.Execute(w, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        http.Error(w, "Internal server error", http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }
}

func submitHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    decoder := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)

    var receipt Receipt
    err := decoder.Decode(&receipt)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        http.Error(w, "Bad request", http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }

    receiptIDCounter++
    receipt.ReceiptID = receiptIDCounter
    receipts[receipt.ReceiptID] = receipt

    jsonResponse, err := json.Marshal(map[string]int{"receiptID": receipt.ReceiptID})
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        http.Error(w, "Internal server error", http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    w.Write(jsonResponse)
}

func receiptHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    vars := mux.Vars(r)
    id, err := strconv.Atoi(vars["id"])
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        http.Error(w, "Bad request", http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }

    receipt, exists := receipts[id]
    if !exists {
        http.NotFound(w, r)
        return
    }

    t, err := template.ParseFiles("templates/receipt.html")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        http.Error(w, "Internal server error", http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    err = t.Execute(w, receipt)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        http.Error(w, "Internal server error", http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }
}
```

This is my home.html which the html for my homepage

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Receipt Input Form</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Receipt Input Form</h1>
    <form id="receipt-form">
        <label>Retailer:</label>
        <input type="text" name="retailer" required><br><br>
        
        <label>Purchase Date:</label>
        <input type="date" name="purchaseDate" required><br><br>
        
        <label>Purchase Time:</label>
        <input type="time" name="purchaseTime" required><br><br>
        
        <div id="items">
            <div class="item">
                <label>Short Description:</label>
                <input type="text" name="shortDescription[]" required>
                
                <label>Price:</label>
                <input type="number" name="price[]" step="0.01" min="0" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="button" id="add-item-btn">Add Item</button><br><br>
        
        <label>Total:</label>
        <input type="number" name="total" step="0.01" min="0" required><br><br>
        
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var itemCount = 1;
            $('#add-item-btn').click(function() {
                itemCount++;
                var newItem = '<div class="item"><label>Short Description:</label>' +
                    '<input type="text" name="shortDescription[]" required>' +
                    '<label>Price:</label>' +
                    '<input type="number" name="price[]" step="0.01" min="0" required>' +
                    '<button type="button" class="remove-item-btn">Remove Item</button>' +
                    '</div>';
                $('#items').append(newItem);
            });
            
            $(document).on('click', '.remove-item-btn', function() {
                $(this).parent().remove();
                itemCount--;
            });
            
            $('#receipt-form').submit(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var form = $(this).serializeArray();
                var items = [];
                $('.item').each(function() {
                    var item = {};
                    item.shortDescription = $(this).find('input[name="shortDescription[]"]').val();
                    item.price = $(this).find('input[name="price[]"]').val();
                    items.push(item);
                });
                form.push({ name: "items", value: JSON.stringify(items) });
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/submit",
                    data: form,
                    success: function(response) {
                        window.location.href = "/receipt?id=" + response.receiptID;
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                        console.log(xhr.responseText);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my receipt.html which is the html for the receipt page after the receipt gets submitted.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Receipt Details</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Receipt Details</h1>
    <ul>
        <li>Retailer: {{.Retailer}}</li>
        <li>Purchase Date: {{.PurchaseDate}}</li>
        <li>Purchase Time: {{.PurchaseTime}}</li>
        <li>Items:</li>
        <ul>
            {{range .Items}}
            <li>{{.ShortDescription}} - {{.Price}}</li>
            {{end}}
        </ul>
        <li>Total: {{.Total}}</li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried different ways of serialization but haven't got anything to work. When I fill out the forms for the receipt then hit submit, I expect that I get taken to the receipt page showing unique details for that receipt. However I'm just getting an error, my most recent one being this:
`invalid character 'r' looking for beginning of value`

Comment: Part of the problem is how you're grabbing the data to serialize into JSON. Try logging out `form` and you'll see you get some urlencoded JSON inside the `items` key: `[{\&quot;shortDescription\&quot;:\&quot;asdf\&quot;,\&quot;price\&quot;:\&quot;3\&quot;}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update your `home.html` as below. I changed submit request Content-Type to `application/json` because `submitHandler` in the server is looking for an `JSON`.

```js
$('#receipt-form').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    
    var form = $(this).serializeArray();

    var formObject = {};
    $.each(form,
        function(i, v) {
            if (v.name != "price[]" && v.name != "shortDescription[]") {
                formObject[v.name] = v.value;
            }
        });

    var items = [];
    $('.item').each(function() {
        var item = {};
        item.shortDescription = $(this).find('input[name="shortDescription[]"]').val();
        item.price = $(this).find('input[name="price[]"]').val();
        items.push(item);
    });

    formObject["items"] = items;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/submit",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify(formObject),
        success: function(response) {
            window.location.href = "/receipt?id=" + response.receiptID;
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
});
```